Using application Service Principals to access Azure DevOps
I followed the procedure as outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops.
I created a service principal in Azure. An entry is created in Microsoft Entra ID.
When I try step 2: i.e., adding the service principal as a user in the Azure DevOps organization, I get the following error:
VS403283: Could not add user <guid> at this time.

I used the console.
I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure the Entra ID is connected correctly as I see the service principal in the drop down window of the "Add user UI in Azure DevOps.
Any hints?
Thanks.
